# Finding nth letter in alphabet from current letter

Tags: java, char, ascii, alphabet

So I am trying to take a letter from the *alphabet*, input by the user, and then finding the letter that is *10 letters away*, and I want it to wrap around the alphabet *if the letter is 'z' or 'y'* or anything that is < letter 16.

I am struggling with the looping part. I know that the alphabet is just thrown into the `ASCII table` with numbers that are not 1-26, so I am not sure how to deal with it. This is what I have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input your favorite letter");
    char userLetter = input.next().charAt(0);
    char newLetter = (char) ((userLetter + 10) % 26);

    System.out.println("10 letters beyond your letter is " + newChar);

}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: @JohnForbes Hi John. If you look in my code you can see that I have used modulo for wrapping. The problem is that in the `ASCII table` the alphabet is not numbered 1-26. But I do have an idea now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try mapping both lowercase and uppercase alphabet characters to a 1-26 scale, then shift and possibly wrap using the modulus.  Finally, we keep track of the shift amount, so that we may add it back to generate the shifted character.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please input your favorite letter");
char userLetter = input.next().charAt(0);

// get the ASCII value of the input character
int ascii = (int) userLetter;
// compute the shift (97 for lowercase, 65 for uppercase)
int shift = ascii > 90 ? 97 : 65;

int newPosition = (ascii - shift + 10) % 26;
newPosition += shift;

char newChar = (char) newPosition;
System.out.println("10 letters beyond your letter is " + newChar);
```

Comment: This is a very elegant way to do this. Thank you, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could just use the valueOf combination.

```
String userLetter = ...;
int charValue = userLetter.charAt(0);
String next = String.valueOf((char)(charValue + 10));
```

Then just just an if statement to detect when it reaches A or Z and change it accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

it is called CaesarCipher 
s is your shift count

```
//A Java Program to illustrate Caesar Cipher Technique 
public class CaesarCipher 
{ 
    // Encrypts text using a shift od s 
    public static StringBuffer encrypt(String text, int s) 
    { 
        StringBuffer result= new StringBuffer(); 

        for (int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) 
        { 
            if (Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i))) 
            { 
                char ch = (char)(((int)text.charAt(i) + 
                                s - 65) % 26 + 65); 
                result.append(ch); 
            } 
            else
            { 
                char ch = (char)(((int)text.charAt(i) + 
                                s - 97) % 26 + 97); 
                result.append(ch); 
            } 
        } 
        return result; 
    } 

    // Driver code 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String text = "ATTACKATONCE"; 
        int s = 10; 
        System.out.println("Text : " + text); 
        System.out.println("Shift : " + s); 
        System.out.println("Cipher: " + encrypt(text, s)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input your favorite letter");
    char userLetter = input.next().charAt(0);
    int unumber = (int) userLetter;

    int newNum=unumber+10;


    if(newNum>122 || newNum>90){

        newNum=(unumber)-(26-10);
    }

    char newLetter = (char) (newNum);


    System.out.println("10 letters beyond your letter is " + newLetter);
}
```